# how to join results of two select queries with different columns but same number of rows in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to join the results of two sql queries results in single table, with different columns but same number of rows. My query is given below:

```
SELECT      tbl_StaticIPPool.StaticIPPoolID, StaticIPFrom, StaticIPTo, 
            case when ISNULL(COUNT(tbl_StaticIPs.StaticIPPoolId), 0) = 0 then 'No' else 'Yes' end as IPs_Generated,
            isnull(count(tbl_StaticIPs.StaticIPPoolId), 0) as TotalIPs
FROM        tbl_StaticIPPool
    left outer join tbl_StaticIPs on tbl_StaticIPs.StaticIPPoolId = tbl_StaticIPPool.StaticIPPoolID
    left outer join tbl_Customers on tbl_Customers.CustomerID = tbl_StaticIPs.CustomerID
group by    tbl_StaticIPPool.StaticIPPoolID, StaticIPFrom, StaticIPTo
Order by    StaticIPFrom

select      isnull(count(tbl_StaticIPs.StaticIPPoolId), 0) as Available
from        tbl_StaticIPPool
    left outer join tbl_StaticIPs on tbl_StaticIPs.StaticIPPoolId = tbl_StaticIPPool.StaticIPPoolID
where       tbl_StaticIPs.CustomerID = 0
group by    tbl_StaticIPPool.StaticIPPoolID, StaticIPFrom, StaticIPTo
Order by    StaticIPFrom
```

Comment: You could use them as subqueries and join using `StaticIPPoolID` after that `order by StaticIPFrom`

Comment: you can join using dummy column like `1=1`